# Повтор "я"

Tags: стилистика

Всегда боюсь, чтобы в теКсте много раз подряд не звучало местоимение "я" - нелитературно и как-то даже некрасиво. Но как этого избежать, например, в таком предложении: "Как **я** уже писал, **я** сейчас работаю над книгой..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно заменить на "Как уже было сказано/написано, я сейчас работаю над книгой".
Иногда автор своей книги заменяет "я" на "мы", что делает текст, по-моему, более динамичным и менее эгоистичным.

Answer (score 3):

> > > Всегда боюсь, чтобы в тесте много раз подряд не звучало местоимение "я" - нелитературно и как-то даже некрасиво.

Не надо бояться. Здесь смотрится вполне нормально.

Но можно и опустить, как тут и рекомендовали, в случае, если личная форма глагола позволяет установить лицо.  Хуже, если там прошедшее время. "Как я уже сказал, я тогда  работал над книгой". Ну и как тут опустить "я"? А если уж опускать, то первое из двух. Вариант "как уже было сказано" мне тоже не слишком нравится. Кем сказано, про кого сказано? Да и казёнщиной отдаёт.

Вообще эта рекомендация, "избегать яканья", не очень умными товарищами придумана. Есть у нас такие любители прятаться за мнением коллектива.

И я категорически не согласен с идеей заменять "я" на "мы" в тексте, не являющимся сильно математизированным научным текстом. Там это особый стиль изложения, подчеркивающий, что читающий может повторить действия наравне с пишущим, а у нас-то каким образом "Я писал" можно заменить на "мы писали"? На "мы пахали" разве.

Comment: Да, я тоже против замены "я" на "мы". Ведь, если, например, я пишу книгу, то с какой стати мне писать "мы"? Кто еще в соавторы примазывается?))))

Answer (score 1):

Просто опустить второе "я": *Как я уже писал, сейчас работаю над книгой...*
По-моему, ничего другого здесь не придумаешь...

Answer (score 1):

"Как я уже писал, сейчас я работаю над книгой..." - то есть предлагаю просто местоимение "я" поставить подальше от первого "я", т.е. после слова "сейчас".